# ImageView tint using a selector in SDK 20 and below

Tags: android, imageview

I am working an Android app using SDK 19+. A `RelativeLayout` contains some subviews and is made clickable to work as button:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ImageView
        ...
        android:src="@drawable/image__bank"                
        android:tint="@drawable/bg_selector_image"/>

    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

This works fine to change the button color and image tint on SDK 21+. However on SDK 20 and below loading the layout fails with:

```
Error inflating class ImageView
```

It runs fine on SDK 20 and below when removing `android:tint` or using a color resource instead of a selector.

Is there any *clean* solution to solve this in XML? I already tried to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead, but the problem is still the same.

How to get this running on SDK 20-?

EDIT:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Comment: Which version of the appcompat library are you using? Also, when you say you tried `AppCompatImageView`, were you still using `android:tint`, or did you use that attribute in the app's namespace; e.g., `app:tint`?

Comment: @MikeM `v7:26.1.0`

Comment: Change to using `app:tint`. Before Lollipop, the system `tint` attribute didn't support `ColorStateList`s, so that's why you were getting the Exception, even with `AppCompatImageView`. Since 25.4.1, though, `AppCompatImageView` has it's own `tint` attribute that'll work, but it's in the app's namespace.

Comment: This was way to easy... :-) Thank you very much, this solved the problem of course...

Comment: No problem. Btw, if that layout is being used in an `AppCompatActivity`, you don't need to specify `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>` in the layout. You can just use `<ImageView>`. `AppCompatActivity`'s inflater will make the substitution automatically.